# API exposed to find the device is capable to make call

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Is any API is exposed to get know the device is capable for making call via network carrier. I was looking this in WinRT Universal(8.1). So that i will work in Tab, Surface and also in WindowsPhone.

Comment: this might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452991.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

This api is not available in Universal apps and is only available in Windows Phone.

the api is called **PhoneCallManager**: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.aspx

Universal apps are not 100% truly universal especially if you want to acces phone or tablet specific things like the dialer in Windows Phone or printers in Windows 8. these things are not universal yet so you have to check this in your own code.

Here some example on how to check if your code is being executed by a phone or tablet/pc:

```
#if WINDOWS_APP
            //Do Windows 8.1 tablet/pc stuff
#endif
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            //do Phone specific stuff
#endif
```

source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx#PlatformContext